# Laptop shutting down without overheating

Tags: laptop, shutdown, overheating

I have a 3 years old laptop, and since a while it keeps shutting down after a while without overheating, well that's what i think, the laptop doesn't get warm or whatsoever, also there are no error logs after rebooting so i have no clue whats going on.

I've cleaned the fans already, and got it apart to check if there was more dust in there, and to see if i could find any damage to any hardware, but I didn't see any damage or whatsoever at all.

i got an Asus K53Z laptop.

i hope you guys got any solutions for me.

Comment: https://www.google.iq/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHYD_enAE553AE553&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=laptop%20overheating%20superuser... I think there are lots of questions on superuser - which might address your issue - check them out

Comment: havent found any solutions yet on superuser.. thats why i thought lets make my own post

Comment: Any busted caps in the laptops motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

Press F8 after BIOS screen and choose "Disable reboot on blue screen"(don't exactly know how this called on english). Error codes from BSODs may give us more information about problem.

Comment: I will give that a go, but im not sure if that will work since i never got a BSOD